# How would one convert a Python string representation of a byte-string to an actual byte-string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out how one might convert a string representation of a byte-string into an actual byte-string type. I'm not very used to Python (just hacking on it to help a friend), so I'm not sure if there's some easy "casting" method (like my beloved Java has ;) ). Basically I have a text file, which has as it's contents a byte-string:

```
b'\x03\xacgB\x16\xf3\xe1\\v\x1e\xe1\xa5\xe2U\xf0g\x956#\xc8\xb3\x88\xb4E\x9e\x13\xf9x\xd7\xc8F\xf4'
```

I currently read in this file as follows:

```
aFile = open('test.txt')
x = aFile.read()
print(x) # prints b'\x03\xacgB\x16\xf3\xe1\\v\x1e\xe1\xa5\xe2U\xf0g\x956#\xc8\xb3\x88\xb4E\x9e\x13\xf9x\xd7\xc8F\xf4'
print(type(x)) # prints <class 'str'>
```

How do I make x be of type `<class 'bytes'>`? Thanks for any help.

**Edit:** Having read one of the replies below, I think I'm maybe constraining the question too much. My apologies for that. The input string doens't have to be in python byte-string format (i.e. with the b and the quotation marks), it could just be the plain byte-string:

```
\x03\xacgB\x16\xf3\xe1\\v\x1e\xe1\xa5\xe2U\xf0g\x956#\xc8\xb3\x88\xb4E\x9e\x13\xf9x\xd7\xc8F\xf4
```

If this makes it easier or is better practice, I can use this.

Comment: There is no casting in Python, the concept really doesn't make sense in a dynamic language. It's all duck-typing. If it looks like a str and walks like a str you assume it's a str. And in anyway, how would you "cast" this? If you cast it to a str, you would get a str that starts with b'\x. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your input is in Python's syntax, for some reason (*), the thing to do here is just call `eval`:

```
>>> r"b'\x12\x12'"
"b'\\x12\\x12'"
>>> eval(r"b'\x12\x12'")
'\x12\x12'
```

Be careful, though, as this may be a security problem. `eval` will run *any* code, so you may need to sanitize the input. In your case its simple - just check that the thing you're `eval`-ing is indeed a string in the format you expect. If security isn't an issue here, just don't bother.

**Redarding your EDIT**: Still, `eval` is the simplest approach here (after adding the `b''` if it's not there). You could also, of course, do this manually by converting each `\xXX` to its real value.

---

(*) Why, really? This seems like a strange choice for a data representation format

Comment: The reason was one I've just realised was utterly idiotic. XD. Storing hashed values when playing about, didn't think to use `.hexdigest()` instead of `digest()`. `hexdigest()` of course gives out a string, which is far nicer to play with. Sorry for bothering you with a silly question.

Comment: @Stephen: it's OK, as long as you got help ;-) Having format like this is an obvious "code smell", so I pointed it out

Comment: @Stephen: Bytes are nice to play with to (but ok, maybe not AS nice), the question is why you wrote the representation of bytes to the file instead of the bytes themselves.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> r'\x03\xacgB\x16\xf3\xe1\\v\x1e\xe1\xa5\xe2U\xf0g\x956#\xc8\xb3\x88\xb4E\x9e\x13\xf9x\xd7\xc8F\xf4'.decode('string-escape')
'\x03\xacgB\x16\xf3\xe1\\v\x1e\xe1\xa5\xe2U\xf0g\x956#\xc8\xb3\x88\xb4E\x9e\x13\xf9x\xd7\xc8F\xf4'
```

This will work for strings that don't have `b'...'` around it. Otherwise you are encouraged to use `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: For reasons that are beyond me, `ast.literal_eval()` does not work for `b''` literals in Python 3.x -- that's why I deleted my answer.

Comment: @Sven: Weird. Works fine on 2.7.

Comment: @Sven: Huh, you're right. Do you know if there's an open bug report for that?

Comment: @Sven: literal_eval can apparently handle bytes from 3.2. Don't know why it was omitted before that.

Comment: it should be `.decode('unicode_escape')` on Python3.

Comment: ... which must be called on a `bytes` object, and should be followed by `.encode('latin-1')` to obtain the intended `bytes` object.