# how to convert python binary str literal to real bytes

Tags: python

In python 3, I have a str like this, which is the exactly literal representation of bytes data:

```
'8\x81p\x925\x00\x003dx\x91P\x00x\x923\x00\x00\x91Pd\x00\x921d\x81p1\x00\x00'
```

I would like to convert it to real byte,

```
b'8\x81p\x925\x00\x003dx\x91P\x00x\x923\x00\x00\x91Pd\x00\x921d\x81p1\x00\x00'
```

I tried to use .encode() on the str data, but the result added many "xc2":

```
b'8\xc2\x81p\xc2\x925\x00\x003dx\xc2\x91P\x00x\xc2\x923\x00\x00\xc2\x91Pd\x00\xc2\x921d\xc2\x81p1\x00\x00'.
```

I also tried:

```
import ast

ast.literal_eval("b'8\x81p\x925\x00\x003dx\x91P\x00x\x923\x00\x00\x91Pd\x00\x921d\x81p1\x00\x00'")
```

The result is:

```
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

How to convert the str input to the bytes as exactly the same as follows?

```
b'8\x81p\x925\x00\x003dx\x91P\x00x\x923\x00\x00\x91Pd\x00\x921d\x81p1\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would one convert a Python string representation of a byte-string to an actual byte-string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281799/how-would-one-convert-a-python-string-representation-of-a-byte-string-to-an-actu)

Comment: no, just tried that solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with the encode function already. Just try with this encoding:

```
>>> '8\x81p\x925\x00\x003dx\x91P\x00x\x923\x00\x00\x91Pd\x00\x921d\x81p1\x00\x00'.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
b'8\x81p\x925\x00\x003dx\x91P\x00x\x923\x00\x00\x91Pd\x00\x921d\x81p1\x00\x00'
```

I took it from [this table in Python's codecs documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings)

Edit: I just found it needs `raw_unicode_escape` instead of `unicode_escape`

Comment: Cool! Solved my headache! The issue comes the axios post a form with that file and the flask request to receive the file. The received file is always like a str representation of the binary send file, no matter what encoding I tried in the server side. So I now open the received file and use your method to convert the file to bytes. Thank you!