# how to get bytes from enviroment variables without converting into string

Tags: python, environment-variables, byte, .env

I need to read encrypted data from ".env file" or environmental variable which is in bytes format.
`pwd = b'23od0403kjdj4'`. but I'm getting it as string format.`"b'23od0403kjdj4'"` when I tried to convert back into bytes it is converted into `b"b'23od0403kjdj4'"`.

I tried various methods to convert it into bytes none are worked. I need it as bytes format `b'23od0403kjdj4'`. any help.

Comment: environment variables are always strings. You mean you have the value string `"b'...'"`, including the `b`, saved in an ENV variable?

Comment: That looks like your `.env` file literally contains `b'23od0403kjdj4'`. How do you write to it?

Comment: This answer, and the rest of the site gives a decent discussion. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5281840/8472976